# PhpStorm memory usage on Windows 10

Tags: windows, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm installed on Windows 10 operating system.

When I open PhpStorm, in task manager I can find out that memory usage of PhpStorm is about 400MB, but it gradually increasing up to 900MB. When I close all PhpStorm tabs memory usage does not change.

Can any one help about this problem?

Comment: try to open another project - would the memory consumption change? IDE allocates some space in RAM: even if you close opened files this space would be still reserved by IDE. Does it cause you any issues?

Comment: when i open another project and close current project, the memory usage does not change;

Comment: 900MB is a typical memory usage by PhpStorm (Windows 10 x64; using 64-bit bundled JDK). I do not mind even if it will eat 2GB as long as it run smooth -- I'm fine with that/no problems in this regard. Does it cause any issues for you? (Well ... if you have only 4GB RAM in total or slow PC/HDD only then it may ...)